# Inserting lines with common identifier in a thread-safe way

Tags: sql, sql-server, thread-safety

I created an application that dynamically creates SQL code.
This application is supposed to group some production orders that are identified by their barcode and that are consolidated into one pick order.

To achieve that I need to write to a SQL Server database:

1. A common identifier
2. Each corresponding barcode
3. The amount of items to be produced

Usually I would create an identity column in SQL Server and query the newly inserted identity with `select scope_identity()` afterwards but I need to use my identifier multiple times.

This is the SQL code my application currenty generates:

```
set xact_abort on 
BEGIN TRAN 

declare @MultiOrderReference as integer
set @MultiOrderReference = (select max(Reference) from PickReference ) + 1
insert into PickReference (Reference, Barcode, Amount) values (@MultiOrderReference, '0068518000', 1)
insert into PickReference (Reference, Barcode, Amount) values (@MultiOrderReference, '0068548000', 4)
insert into PickReference (Reference, Barcode, Amount) values (@MultiOrderReference, '0068550000', 8)

select @MultiOrderReference as Reference
commit tran
```

This inserts the lines with a common identifier and gives the identifier back to the application afterwards.

This will work most of the times and considering these are very small transactions (fast) it will probably always work but to my understanding it is not Thread-Safe. So if another user runs the application at the exact same time I guess two application instances can use the same common identifier in theory.
Is there a way to prevent that? Or am I wrong and this is in fact Thread-Safe since I'm using "begin tran  -> commit tran"?

Comment: Perhaps you actually need *two* tables. Difficult to truly know from the above.

Comment: Use sequences instead of MAX(something). Unless you sit on sql server 2008 or so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you should just use a `SEQUENCE`.

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.PickId AS int
  START WITH 1;
```

Then get the value for it.

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRAN;

DECLARE @MultiOrderReference int = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.PickId;

INSERT INTO PickReference (Reference, Barcode, Amount)
VALUES
(@MultiOrderReference, '0068518000', 1),
(@MultiOrderReference, '0068548000', 4),
(@MultiOrderReference, '0068550000', 8);

COMMIT;

SELECT @MultiOrderReference AS Reference;
```

---

If you *really* want to stick with your existing code, then you need to add locking hints: both `SERIALIZABLE` and `UPDLOCK`. You should also add an index on `Reference`.

```sql
set @MultiOrderReference = isnull((
    select max(Reference)
    from PickReference with (serializable, updlock)
), 0) + 1;
```

Comment: Already implemented and SEQUENCE works perfectly. Also "NOCOUNT" gives less spam back to my application.
May I ask if there is a specific benefit of adding a semicolon at the end of each line like you did?

Comment: *Not* terminating your statements is deprecated, @MikeFUT , and there are some statements that require the prior statement to be properly terminated (and I think `MERGE` must be terminated as well, but I always Upsert so I might be misremembering). As such it's best practice to always terminate your statements, as you don't encounter "gotchas" and you're future proofing your code for if/when Microsoft mandate the behaviour.